# How to get the value of field

Tags: reflection, julia

In julia i can get a list of fields  like so

```
INPUT:
type Foobar
    foo::Int
    bar::String
end

baz = Foobar(5,"GoodDay")
fieldnames(baz)

OUTPUT:
2-element Array{Symbol,1}:
 :foo
 :bar
```

But how can access the values of those fields, given the names that I am finding dynamically?

#### I know one way is to build the expression myself:

```
fieldvalue(v,fn::Symbol) = eval(Expr(:(.), v, QuoteNode(fn)))
```

That is kinda scary looking, so I think there is a better way.

#### Usecase:

```
INPUT:
function print_structure(v)
    for fn in fieldnames(v)
        println(fn,"\t", fieldvalue(v,fn))
    end   
end
print_structure(baz)

OUTPUT:
foo 5
bar GoodDay
```

Comment: @DanGetz that sounds like an answer. How about you make it one so I can upvote and accept?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getfield(baz, :foo)` will get the field `foo` from variable `baz` i.e. the result will be the same as `baz.foo`.

Note `:foo` has to be a symbol, therefore if you somehow get the field name in a string, it should be used as follows: `getfield(varname, Symbol(fieldnamestring))`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use e.g. getfield(baz, 2) to get the 2nd field without needing to know its name.